# Is it possible to access the iPhone "Favorite" numbers?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, addressbook, favorites

I want to access the iPhone "Favorites" numbers (the ones that can be found in the "Phone" application). I've searched among the properties specific to each contact from the Address Book and I even had a look at the Address Book database, but I couldn't identify which property or field from the database indicates which are the favorite numbers.

Since "Phone" is an application installed by Apple on the iPhone I was expecting to find such a property in the database. However, I think that it might be possible that this application stores the favorite numbers independently of the Address Book database.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and if yes, could you please clarify this matter for me?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. I would expect the "Phone" application itself stores the most used numbers without exposing this infomation to other applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was suspecting that it isn't possible, but I needed a confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [Find Favorite contacts from the iOS Address Book API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917329/find-favorite-contacts-from-the-ios-address-book-api)

It's currently not possible to access favorite contacts via a public, app-store legal API.