# iOS : Get favorite contacts list in Contacts Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Is there any way that we can get the list of the favorite contacts, as it appears on the iOS dialer?

Edit : As stated in the title i am looking for an answer throught the new Contacts Framework and not the AddressBook API specified in the link : [Find Favorite contacts from the iOS Address Book API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917329/find-favorite-contacts-from-the-ios-address-book-api)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917329/find-favorite-contacts-from-the-ios-address-book-api

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!