# How can I determine that CNContact is is favorites?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, contacts, favorites, cncontact

My iOS application fetches contacts from device using code

```
[[CNContactStore new] requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
  if (granted) {
    NSArray *keys = @[CNContactNamePrefixKey,
                      CNContactGivenNameKey,
                      CNContactMiddleNameKey,
                      CNContactFamilyNameKey,
                      // ...
    NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
    NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
    for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
      // contacts fetching
    }
  }
}];
```

Has CNContact class some value means that contact is in favorites on device (in Phone application)? I didn't found such key in CNContact keys.

Or maybe predicate contains keys that I needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filip Radelic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877465/filip-radelic) answered same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917329/find-favorite-contacts-from-the-ios-address-book-api):

> Favorites are stored inside Phone.app, not inside the Address Book database itself. You can't access other app's sandbox on a non-jailbroken iPhone, so unfortunately the answer is no.
>
> Also, it would be pretty bad for privacy if any app could see your favorite contacts. It's already bad that it can access entire address book without asking you.

Comment: Is this still true even when using Contacts?